# Testing if Windows product key is valid

Tags: windows, license-key, product-key

I want to buy a Windows Vista product key from what appears to be an old laptop. I was wondering how I can test if it still works (because I am aware of certain limitations on the number of computer you can register a key on). The idea I had is to create a VM with Windows Vista, disconnect it from the Internet and then use the key on it. If it works - just delete the VM.

Should this work in practice?

Also is it possible the key to be tied to the specific laptop it came from?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Contact windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take care about OEM keys (attached to the material). If Vista came preinstalled on your computer, or you bought an OEM Licence/Download, it is classified as an OEM licence and is non-transferable.

**Check if a key is an OEM key**

Open a command line on your old computer and type :

```
slmgr.vbs /dlv
```

If you have an OEM key you will see at the third line :

> Description: Windows(R) Operating System, OEM_DM channel

For a retail version you will see later in the text :

> mx?configextension=Retail

If you have a retail key there is no problem, you may transfer it to another computer/laptop as much as you want. But, it may only be installed on one computer at a time. Your old computer will be automatically desactivated.

Comment: As the computer is not mine, I cannot do this myself. But thanks for the info, I will check about this. However this still does not completely answer my question: how do I know the guy I am buying the key hasn't already registered it 10 times and when I try to register it I would get an error?

Comment: As i said, if you have a retail version you can transfer it as many time as you want. But your old computer will be desactivated.
The rule is simple : One Licence = One Installation, if you remove your old installation, there is no problem to reuse a retail key.

Comment: @BozhidarGanev : Moreover, your test with the VM is not correct. Because without internet, the installation program will check if the key is "mathematically" correct regarding to the verification algorithm. But you don't know if the key is not banned, OEM, AA or Retail version. As soon as you transfer the key to your new computer (connected to the internet) you may have some problems.